# Euler's phi function application

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, totient-function

Please advise on how to solve the following textbook question below:

**Let phi(n)/n = a/b. Where n = positive odd integer and a and b are relatively prime.**

**Prove that the largest prime factor of n = largest prime factor of b**

So far I have thought of using prime factorization 
φ(n)/n = {(p1-1)(p2-1)...(pr 1)}/p1*p2*...*pr

I'm not sure where to go from here. Should I conduct proof by cases?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: if $P$ is the largest prime factor of $n$, to prove the statement it suffices to show that $P$ does not divide $\phi(n)$.

Comment: Suppose the largest prime factor of $n$ is $p$ and appears $k$ times in the factorisation, i.e. $p^k\mid n$ but $p^{k+1} \not \mid n$. The question is essentially to show that $p^k\not\mid \varphi(n)$.  Can you show $p^{k-1}\mid \varphi(n)$?

Comment: @GregMartin  $\varphi(9)=6$ which can be divided by $3$ so you need a little more than that

Comment: @Henry excellent point, and your comment provides the right clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n=p^kQ$ where $Q$ is a product of primes less than $p$.

Then $\phi(n)=p^{k-1}(p-1)\phi(Q)$, where $p$ and $\phi(Q)$ are coprime.

Therefore $\frac{\phi(n)}{n}=\frac{(p-1)\phi(Q)}{pQ}$ and the factor of $p$ in the denominator cannot cancel with any factor of the numerator.